# JCo Server - JCoServerFunctionHandler - handleRequest - endless call and TID

Tags: java, jco

Implemented JCo Server at Java, according to sample codes (StepByStepServer).

Created a function inside repository of the JCo Server.

JCo Server is starting normally.

And I can catch requests inside following function handler.

**Question 1)** Is it normal that handleRequest method in StfcConnectionHandler (implementation of JCoServerFunctionHandler) is called continuously like inside an infinite loop?

**Question 2)** Inside handleRequest TID of request ( serverCtx.getTID() ) is always Null.

Is TID sent from SAP side?

```
public class StfcConnectionHandler implements JCoServerFunctionHandler {

//Properties

@Override
public void handleRequest(JCoServerContext serverCtx, JCoFunction function) throws AbapException
{
        …// Endless call to this method
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not contain enough information for giving a more sophisticated answer.

Question 1:
No, this is not normal, of course. Every remote function call from ABAP side shall result in a single invocation of `handleRequest(...)`. Only in case of tRFC, qRFC or bgRFC it may occur that the ABAP backend will retry a previously failed invocation.
Please check, if it is your own coding who is doing these repeated invocations, either from ABAP or in Java. Switching on JCo traces and looking into them might be helpful here.

Question 2:
A TID will only be set for tRFC and qRFC calls, but not for the default sRFC calls. For bgRFCs the so called UnitIdentifier will be set instead of a TID.

I hope this helps nevertheless.

```
*) Legend:
   sRFC  = synchronous RFC
   tRFC  = transactional RFC
   qRFC  = queued RFC
   bgRFC = background RFC
```

Comment: Thanks for answers. If ABAP call my function (let say Z_TEST_FUNCTION) and I can read import variables of this function during call in handleRequest. And I want to respond to this call. Is it enough just to set value to export parameter (O_REQUEST_RESULT) of function Z_TEST_FUNCTION like: function.getExportParameterList().setValue("O_REQUEST_RESULT", "my answer to Abap call...");    ,    I mean do I need to do something like function.Execute(jcoDestination) ?

Comment: Yes, calling function.getExportParameterList().setValue("O_REQUEST_RESULT‌​", "my answer to Abap call..."); is all you need to do in the handleRequest(...) implementation. Export, Changing and Table parameters are sent back to the caller. Of course, you can only set parameters which are also defined in your function interface at ABAP side. And also note that tRFC, qRFC and bgRFC cannot send back any return parameters, this is only possible with synchronous RFC calls where the caller is waiting for the response in order to process it.

Comment: Thanks for info! And also how can I call function.getExportParameterList().setValue("O_REQUEST_RESULT‌​‌​", "my answer to Abap call..."); out of the handleReuest? I mean I need to send a message to SAP. This message is not a response to SAP call it is a new request to SAP side.

Comment: As said, Export, Changing and Table parameters are sent back to the caller. This is always done automatically in an sRFC JCoServer processing. You get the JCoFunction object as argument in handleRequest(...). I think that I have answered your initial question now, so it would be nice if you could also mark it as accepted answer.
If you have further questions, e.g. how to do RFC client calls from Java to ABAP, then would you please ask a new question? StackOverflow is not a forum for doing lengthy discussions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: It's not usual that the call happens in an endless loop but I've seen that (not endless but with a number of tries) if the request is expected to be asynchronous and you take too long to finish `handleRequest`. An example is the implementation of `IDOC_INBOUND_ASYNCHRONOUS` where I've received the same IDoc over and over again, because it took me longer than 3 seconds to handle the request (the same system took 3 minutes to handle when I was sending Idocs, but that's a different story ;-)

Question 2: Have you set a class implementing `JCoServerTIDHandler` as TIDHandler when setting up the `JCoServer`? Without a TIDHandler there are no TIDs.